# How can I modify strings in a table

Tags: sql

I have these rows in my table:product in details column

```
Product P0001 has 1587 samples
Product P0002 has 5454 samples
...
```

I wanna alter these rows using an sql query to be:

```
Produit P0001 a 1587 échantillons
Produit P0002 a 5454 échantillons
...
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Which database are you using? I think you should be able to use `replace` function

Comment: Hey @Neila. Please update your question to include your table structure, the queries and things you've tried and why those solutions didn't work.

Comment: Err, it looks like you're attempting to update with a translated version.  Why?  Do you not need, potentially, both (or more than 2 languages)?  I'm also concerned that you have some counted information in that string (that's not being updated) - potentially, it should be gathered dynamically...

Comment: I didn't know why I have -3 in vote !!! so strange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this update:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourField = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(YourField, 'Product', 'Produit'), 'has', 'a'), 'samples', 'échantillons')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
update mytable set myfield =
REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(myfield, 'Product', 'Produit')
    , 'has', 'a')
, 'samples', 'échantillons')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this one-

```
UPDATE dbo.Product Set <col1> = 'a', <col2>='échantillons' where <col1> = 'has'
```